# SES not allow to authenticate

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, telnet

SES not allow me to authenticate. 
I can able to telnet on port 25 but whenever I am giving "AUTH LOGIN" below commands the connection was lost.

```
$ telnet.exe email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com 25
Trying 54.187.123.10...
Connected to email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 email-smtp.amazonaws.com ESMTP SimpleEmailService-1207632523 AyQgU69E2tr9zUK96DuI
ehlo example.com
250-email-smtp.amazonaws.com
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 10485760
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250 Ok
STARTTLS
220 Ready to start TLS
AUTH LOGIN

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I am following below link:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-client-command-line.html

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`220 Ready to start TLS` has to be followed by TLS negotiation from your side.  You can't send cleartext after that, as you are doing.

To test interactively from the command line, follow the examples using `openssl s_client`, which you can think of as "ssl telnet," if that helps. That isn't precisely accurate, but in this case, it's close enough.